# doAsync does not work in a Fragment class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using Kotlin language for the android application I am building and I use doAsync for getting data from a JSON.

First I did it in the MainActivity which extends `AppCompatibility()` and it worked, but now I also have to get some data from another JSON in another class which extends `Fragment()` and apparently it does not work because it does not enter inside the Async method when I debug the application.

**This is the code I have:**

```
class CreatePayment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    lateinit var rootView: View
    lateinit var bEndDay: Button
    lateinit var bEndMonth: Button
    lateinit var bEndYear: Button
    private val ipServer = "http://192.168.1.38"
    private val key = "my_key"
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_payment, container, false)
        return rootView
    }
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        bEndDay = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bEndDay)
        bEndDay.setOnClickListener(this)
        bEndMonth = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bEndMonth)
        bEndMonth.setOnClickListener(this)
        bEndYear = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bEndYear)
        bEndYear.setOnClickListener(this)
        getFrmTexts()
    }
    private fun getFrmTexts() {
        doAsync {
            val result = URL(ipServer + ":3001/api/users?key=" + key).readText()
            uiThread {
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(result) //never enters here
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val ipServer = "http://192.168.56.1"
    private val key = "my_key"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val etLoginUser = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etLoginUser)
        val etLoginPassword = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etLoginPasword)
        val bLogin = findViewById<Button>(R.id.bLogin)
        bLogin.setOnClickListener {
            val password = encryptPassword(etLoginPassword.text.toString())
            checkLogin(etLoginUser.text.toString(), password)

        }
    }
    private fun checkLogin(etUser: String, etPassword: String) {
        doAsync {
            val result = URL(ipServer + ":3001/api/users?key=" + key).readText()
            uiThread {
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(result) //always enters here
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val user = jsonObject.getString("user")
                    val password = jsonObject.getString("password")
                    if(user == etUser && password == etPassword) {
                        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, UserActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the result:**
[image]

As you can see, the debugger has stopped in the break-line. However, it does not happen in the `CreatePayment : Fragment() class`:

[image]

And yes, I am sure that the application, enters to this function because if I put a breakpoint in the `doAsync` line, the debugger stops there:

[image]

If I do a step over:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Does `doAsync` work in `AppCompatibility()`classes only?

Answer (score 0):

Call the method `getFrmTexts()` from the fragment's `onViewCreated()` method rather than the `onActivityCreated()` method. `onActivityCreated()` is immediately called after the parent activity's `onCreate()` method so at this time, the fragment might not even have its views ready. Also `uiThread` works differently for different classes.

**Extra tip**

Setting the UI should ideally be done in the `onViewCreated()` method where the view is already available. So you also don't need to save the `rootView` variable in your fragment class from the `onCreateView()` method

Comment: I have just tried to call it from ```onViewCreated()```as you suggested and it does not work either. I even tried to show a toast inside the ```doAsync``` and it did not show up, if I put it outside, it does. As for ```rootView``` goes, I am not sure if I can do that since I use it later and ```onViewCreated()``` does not have the variables ```inflater``` nor ```container``` on its parameters